# "LOADING" message generated at the bottom of the page in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am building a basic jqm page and at the end of the page I am getting a big  tag with the text "loading". I have seen a lot of answers but no one working for me. I have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>StackMob JS SDK Examples</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_migrate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery_mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.stackmob.com/js/stackmob-js-0.7.0-bundled-min.js"></script>   
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function(){
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div data-role="page"> 
    <div data-role="header">...</div> 
    <input type="button" value="bbbb" id="bb">
    <div data-role="content">...</div> 
  <div data-role="footer">...</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

and this in my main.js file:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
});


jQuery('document').ready(function() {
    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
    jQuery('#bb').click(function(){
        $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();  
    });
});
```

Nothing is working! Thanks!

Comment: yes, a massage now would be nice ;-)

Comment: Seems like my case. I was loading wrong css file (jquery css instead of jquery mobile css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it during mobileinit event, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
        $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
    })
</script>
```

One more thing, this must be done before jQuery Mobile is loaded, like this:

```
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).bind('mobileinit',function(){
            $.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
        })
    </script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
```

Here's an jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/RwRx9/

More about this can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely remove the loading message, there is a global property to set that

```
$.mobile.loadingMessage = false;
```

If you want to do it in page level. Bind it inside the "mobileinit" function.

```
$("your page").on("pageinit", function(){
   // hide here
});
```